How to compile to RISC-V?
I'm writing the final stage for my compiler to riscv; however, I have run into a minor issue of figuring out what the start point of the program is. Are we guaranteed that the PC starts execution with the first instruction under .text? Some example code I've seen makes this assumption, but when I compile gcc to assembly, either I only see main (MacOS) or I see _start (Linux) but it is not at the start of .text.

"Are we guaranteed that the PC starts execution with the first instruction under .text" — generally, no, though it depends on the loader and the file format.  Most operating systems use a loader customized for their particular favored executable file format, and these generally have an indication of the entry point for the executable, which is the address of the first instruction to run after operating system loading of the program.  This address starts execution of the program and to be clear it is not "called" by the OS, as in function call, and it cannot "return" to the OS.

Do you know how it would be on bare-metal? @ErikEidt I found on Linux a _start exists that you see only after linking, but on MacOS, when you dump the executable, that doesn't even show up.

Are you asking about bare metal or MacOS?

Sorry, there were two questions there. A separate question and a follow-up to your comment asking about _start.

Bare metal depends on the processor first: most processors specify the address of the first instruction, and second the boot mechanism if your code runs after that.

@user129393192 On macOS, the label is just start.
